# simple_captcha error causes 500 error on Heroku but runs correct on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, captcha

I have an error for my application only on heroku and `heroku run rake db:migrate` does not appear to be the solution. On local host everything works perfectly, including the captcha validation for creating a pin.

Here is what I get in the Heroku logs that I believe the error may stem from:
    `ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "simple_captcha_data" does not exist`

Here is the entirety of the heroku logs:

```
2013-11-21T22:41:35.691443+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 257ms (Views: 217.2ms | ActiveRecord: 38.5ms)
2013-11-21T22:41:35.691443+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (227.9ms)
2013-11-21T22:41:35.691443+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (245.4ms)
2013-11-21T22:41:45.178873+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pins/new" for 173.254.206.44 at 2013-11-21 22:41:45 +0000
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209196+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209196+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"simple_captcha_data"'::reg...
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209196+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209196+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209196+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209196+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209380+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209196+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209380+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209196+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"simple_captcha_data"'::regclass
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209196+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209380+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:   <%= f.input :description, label: "Description", as: :text, input_html: { rows: "3" } %>
2013-11-21T22:41:45.217771+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/pins/new host=community.whatyoutheat.com fwd="173.254.206.44" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=37ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209196+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "simple_captcha_data" does not exist
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209380+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <%= show_simple_captcha( :label => "human authentication",:object => "pin") %>  
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209380+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   <%= f.input :tag_list, label: "Tags (seperated by commas)", as: :text, input_html: { rows: "1" } %>
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209380+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= f.input :country, label: "Country", required: true, as: :text, input_html: { rows: "1" } %>
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209380+00:00 app[web.1]:     13: 
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209380+00:00 app[web.1]:     12: 
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209380+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/_form.html.erb:11:in `block in _app_views_pins__form_html_erb__25703674358122578_70142799395160'
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209520+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209520+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209520+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#new as HTML
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209520+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_form.html.erb (15.6ms)
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209380+00:00 app[web.1]:     14: 
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209520+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209520+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_pins_new_html_erb___3000062795534295837_70142799344040'
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209520+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_pins__form_html_erb__25703674358122578_70142799395160'
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209520+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:37:in `new'
2013-11-21T22:41:45.209520+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/new.html.erb within layouts/application (16.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:42:03.779499+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/pins/new host=community.whatyoutheat.com fwd="173.254.206.44" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=53ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-11-21T22:42:03.725783+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pins/new" for 173.254.206.44 at 2013-11-21 22:42:03 +0000
2013-11-21T22:42:03.772805+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-21T22:42:03.772805+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-11-21T22:42:03.772805+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773013+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   <%= f.input :tag_list, label: "Tags (seperated by commas)", as: :text, input_html: { rows: "1" } %>
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773013+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <%= show_simple_captcha( :label => "human authentication",:object => "pin") %>  
2013-11-21T22:42:03.772805+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-11-21T22:42:03.772805+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "simple_captcha_data" does not exist
2013-11-21T22:42:03.772805+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"simple_captcha_data"'::reg...
2013-11-21T22:42:03.772805+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-11-21T22:42:03.772805+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773013+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= f.input :country, label: "Country", required: true, as: :text, input_html: { rows: "1" } %>
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773013+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:   <%= f.input :description, label: "Description", as: :text, input_html: { rows: "3" } %>
2013-11-21T22:42:03.772805+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"simple_captcha_data"'::regclass
2013-11-21T22:42:03.772805+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773013+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773013+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773267+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_pins__form_html_erb__25703674358122578_70142799395160'
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773267+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_pins_new_html_erb___3000062795534295837_70142799344040'
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773267+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:37:in `new'
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773013+00:00 app[web.1]:     12: 
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773013+00:00 app[web.1]:     13: 
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773013+00:00 app[web.1]:     14: 
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773013+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/_form.html.erb:11:in `block in _app_views_pins__form_html_erb__25703674358122578_70142799395160'
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773267+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/new.html.erb within layouts/application (27.3ms)
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773267+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31ms
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773267+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773267+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773267+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#new as HTML
2013-11-21T22:42:03.773267+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_form.html.erb (26.9ms)
2013-11-21T22:42:49.581171+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 184.73.237.85 at 2013-11-21 22:42:49 +0000
2013-11-21T22:42:49.721778+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=protected-anchorage-9119.herokuapp.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=139ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-11-21T22:42:49.713594+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/_home.html.erb (0.8ms)
2013-11-21T22:42:49.713594+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2013-11-21T22:42:49.713594+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (113.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:42:49.713594+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 123ms (Views: 99.2ms | ActiveRecord: 23.3ms)
2013-11-21T22:42:49.713594+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as */*
2013-11-21T22:42:49.713594+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
2013-11-21T22:42:49.713594+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (119.3ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:26.477930+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 54.247.188.179 at 2013-11-21 22:43:26 +0000
2013-11-21T22:43:27.305580+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=protected-anchorage-9119.herokuapp.com fwd="54.247.188.179" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1148ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-11-21T22:43:27.294468+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as */*
2013-11-21T22:43:27.294468+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/_home.html.erb (3.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:27.294468+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (782.5ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:27.294468+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 801ms (Views: 658.9ms | ActiveRecord: 140.5ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:27.294468+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:27.294468+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:27.294468+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (794.4ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:32.947868+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 50.31.164.139 at 2013-11-21 22:43:32 +0000
2013-11-21T22:43:33.228030+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as */*
2013-11-21T22:43:33.228030+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (200.1ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:33.228030+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (210.4ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:33.228030+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.2ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:33.228030+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:33.228030+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 230ms (Views: 168.3ms | ActiveRecord: 60.7ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:33.228030+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/_home.html.erb (1.2ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:33.241042+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=protected-anchorage-9119.herokuapp.com fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=305ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-11-21T22:43:35.371043+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 50.112.95.211 at 2013-11-21 22:43:35 +0000
2013-11-21T22:43:35.631718+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=protected-anchorage-9119.herokuapp.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=263ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-11-21T22:43:35.625502+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as */*
2013-11-21T22:43:35.625502+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:35.625502+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:35.625502+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 241ms (Views: 169.9ms | ActiveRecord: 70.5ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:35.625502+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (228.1ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:35.625502+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (237.1ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:35.625502+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/_home.html.erb (0.9ms)
2013-11-21T22:43:59.333511+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/new" for 173.254.206.44 at 2013-11-21 22:43:59 +0000
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337268+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337268+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/new"):
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337268+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337268+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337268+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337268+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337268+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337268+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337268+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337268+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337555+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337555+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337555+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337555+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337555+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337555+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337555+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337555+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-21T22:43:59.337555+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-21T22:44:23.231692+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pins/new" for 173.254.206.44 at 2013-11-21 22:44:23 +0000
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262385+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262385+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "simple_captcha_data" does not exist
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262385+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"simple_captcha_data"'::reg...
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262385+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262385+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262385+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262385+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262385+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262385+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"simple_captcha_data"'::regclass
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262385+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262569+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262569+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262569+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= f.input :country, label: "Country", required: true, as: :text, input_html: { rows: "1" } %>
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262569+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:   <%= f.input :description, label: "Description", as: :text, input_html: { rows: "3" } %>
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262569+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   <%= f.input :tag_list, label: "Tags (seperated by commas)", as: :text, input_html: { rows: "1" } %>
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262569+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <%= show_simple_captcha( :label => "human authentication",:object => "pin") %>  
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262569+00:00 app[web.1]:     12: 
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262569+00:00 app[web.1]:     13: 
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262569+00:00 app[web.1]:     14: 
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262569+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/_form.html.erb:11:in `block in _app_views_pins__form_html_erb__25703674358122578_70142799395160'
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262712+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_pins__form_html_erb__25703674358122578_70142799395160'
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262712+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_pins_new_html_erb___3000062795534295837_70142799344040'
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262712+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:37:in `new'
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262712+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262712+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262712+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#new as HTML
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262712+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_form.html.erb (14.6ms)
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262712+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/new.html.erb within layouts/application (15.1ms)
2013-11-21T22:44:23.262712+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 20ms
2013-11-21T22:44:49.610891+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 184.73.237.85 at 2013-11-21 22:44:49 +0000
2013-11-21T22:44:49.793026+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as */*
2013-11-21T22:44:49.793026+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/_home.html.erb (0.9ms)
2013-11-21T22:44:49.793026+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (165.4ms)
2013-11-21T22:44:49.793026+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (170.9ms)
2013-11-21T22:44:49.793026+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
2013-11-21T22:44:49.793026+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:44:49.793026+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 176ms (Views: 142.6ms | ActiveRecord: 32.2ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:25.696091+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 54.247.188.179 at 2013-11-21 22:45:25 +0000
2013-11-21T22:45:25.805281+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=protected-anchorage-9119.herokuapp.com fwd="54.247.188.179" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=105ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-11-21T22:45:25.796352+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as */*
2013-11-21T22:45:25.796352+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/_home.html.erb (0.8ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:25.796352+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (87.9ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:25.796352+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (92.3ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:25.796352+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:25.796352+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:25.796352+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 96ms (Views: 74.5ms | ActiveRecord: 20.7ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:32.923240+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 50.31.164.139 at 2013-11-21 22:45:32 +0000
2013-11-21T22:45:33.063337+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as */*
2013-11-21T22:45:33.063337+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/_home.html.erb (0.8ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:33.063337+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (125.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:33.063337+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (130.5ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:33.063337+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:33.063337+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:33.063337+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 135ms (Views: 98.3ms | ActiveRecord: 35.7ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:33.069454+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=protected-anchorage-9119.herokuapp.com fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno=web.1 connect=9ms service=146ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-11-21T22:45:35.347554+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 50.112.95.211 at 2013-11-21 22:45:35 +0000
2013-11-21T22:45:35.526133+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as */*
2013-11-21T22:45:35.526133+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/_home.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:35.526133+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (164.8ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:35.526133+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (169.7ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:35.526133+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:35.526133+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:45:35.526133+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 173ms (Views: 138.8ms | ActiveRecord: 33.9ms)
2013-11-21T22:44:23.266361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/pins/new host=community.whatyoutheat.com fwd="173.254.206.44" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=36ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-11-21T22:43:59.482509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/new host=community.whatyoutheat.com fwd="173.254.206.44" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=159ms status=404 bytes=728
2013-11-21T22:46:49.589049+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 184.73.237.85 at 2013-11-21 22:46:49 +0000
2013-11-21T22:46:49.692342+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as */*
2013-11-21T22:46:49.692342+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/_home.html.erb (0.8ms)
2013-11-21T22:46:49.692342+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (88.9ms)
2013-11-21T22:46:49.692342+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (93.9ms)
2013-11-21T22:46:49.692342+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-11-21T22:46:49.692342+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:46:49.692342+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 98ms (Views: 75.7ms | ActiveRecord: 21.3ms)
2013-11-21T22:46:49.701382+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=protected-anchorage-9119.herokuapp.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=109ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-11-21T22:44:49.796410+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=protected-anchorage-9119.herokuapp.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=190ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-11-21T22:47:25.924030+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 54.247.188.179 at 2013-11-21 22:47:25 +0000
2013-11-21T22:47:26.056801+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as */*
2013-11-21T22:47:26.056801+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/_home.html.erb (0.8ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:26.056801+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (114.2ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:26.056801+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (119.7ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:26.056801+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:26.056801+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:26.056801+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 124ms (Views: 100.8ms | ActiveRecord: 22.1ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:26.071356+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=protected-anchorage-9119.herokuapp.com fwd="54.247.188.179" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=144ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-11-21T22:47:32.913335+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 50.31.164.139 at 2013-11-21 22:47:32 +0000
2013-11-21T22:47:33.076316+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as */*
2013-11-21T22:47:33.076316+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/_home.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:33.076316+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (145.3ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:33.076316+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (151.6ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:33.076316+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:33.076316+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:33.076316+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 156ms (Views: 124.8ms | ActiveRecord: 30.3ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:33.084706+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=protected-anchorage-9119.herokuapp.com fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=171ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-11-21T22:47:35.373343+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 50.112.95.211 at 2013-11-21 22:47:35 +0000
2013-11-21T22:47:35.549639+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as */*
2013-11-21T22:47:35.549639+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/_home.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:35.549639+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (163.8ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:35.549639+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (168.2ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:35.549639+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:35.549639+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:35.549639+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 172ms (Views: 142.6ms | ActiveRecord: 28.5ms)
2013-11-21T22:47:35.562890+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=protected-anchorage-9119.herokuapp.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=184ms status=200 bytes=0
```

I'm not sure what to do here. You can find this project at http://www.github.com/harrisongill/whatyoutheat. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: there's a missing relation. did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: Yes, I did run `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the migration you need is missing entirely from your repo.  I'm not sure if you have a local copy, but there doesn't appear to be any migration that creates the simple_captcha_data table in your repository.

Do a search for 'simple_captcha_data' on Github in your repo and you'll see that it only appears in your db/schema.rb.  So either you didn't check in a migration file, or you ran it locally and deleted it at some point.

Comment: I'm thinking the latter may have been more probable.

Comment: So you need to recreate the migration and ideally totally rebuild your local development database fresh from the migrations

Comment: Thanks Peter. I was able to get this working with `rake db:reset` which I found by looking up rebuilding the database. I was wondering if you know why after that process the captchas will work on localhost but not Heroku by any chance?

Comment: db:reset just resets the database from the db/schema.rb file which, as I note above, is correct.  You are still missing the migration.  You need to recreate the missing migration.

Comment: I reran `rake db:migrate` too right after `rake db:reset`, does that handle it or is there more?

Comment: You need to recreate the migration.  Have you done that?  If you don't have a migration file that recreates the simple_captcha_data table then you need to do that.

Comment: Turns out I just had to run `heroku run rake db:migrate`. Sadly, it runs slower than localhost though, but that is probably related to accessing the data when its live on the web. This problem is now fully solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database is incomplete. Make sure you correctly deployed your code and you run all the necessary migrations before using the app.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails3#rake-and-database-migrations

> Database migrations like above are not run automatically. If you have
>   migrations to run, make sure to run heroku run rake `db:migrate` after a
>   deploy. You can find more on Rake commands.

Comment: Ran it again locally as `rake db:migrate` and on heroku as `heroku run rake db:migrate`. Still getting a 500 error.